# Adding messages to trace log in WCF service?

Tags: c#, logging, wcf, trace

If I have trace logging enabled on a WCF service is it possible to write custom messages to it? If so how? If I don't have trace logging enabled will it just not write or will it throw an exception?

Comment: Do you means System.Diagnostics.Trace() ?

Comment: Maybe... will System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("msg"); work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
FileStream traceLog = new FileStream("C:\\log\\Traces.svclog",FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

TextWriterTraceListener myListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(traceLog);

Trace.Listeners.Add(myListener);

myListener.WriteLine("Sending trace information");

Trace.Flush();

myListener.Flush();
```